# Does the use of RNA as a primer affect the accuracy of DNA replication in E.coli?

Tags: biochemistry

DNA polymerases have proof-reading ability, but RNA polymerase does not. Does the use of RNA as a primer affect the accuracy of DNA replication in E.coli? Explain

Answer (score 1):

E.coli use **DNA polymerase** for DNA replication too. **Primase** creates a short oligonucleotid (**primer**) in the start of string and DNA polymerase continues in work. **RNA polymerase** is using in synthesis of RNA molecules.